# How can I store and persist multiple remoting sessions in an MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-remoting

Imagine a monitoring website that connects to 50 services via .net remoting and polls them to check they are working and find out what they're up to, and display it.

The page uses ajax to hit the backend and the backend then connects to each one.

Ideally, I don't want it to open a connection, do the request, close the connection, for 50 connections, on a 5 second interval (unless this is the best practice way?). So I'd like MVC to persist the connections.

I can make a ConnectionManager static singleton to handle this (not sure where?), opening and closing connections as required/idling.

You could even have a ConnectionManager handle the server status, so if multiple people load the status webpage, the results are cached.

But is there a better way, especially one that is scaleable? You could have multiple ConnectionManager classes in a webfarm scenario as they won't clash afaik (you can have multiple connections open).

ATM I am doing this in my ajax methods:

```
TcpChannel tcpChannel = new TcpChannel();

ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel, false);

Type requiredType = typeof(ICatServerMarshaller);

ICatServerMarshaller remoteObject = (ICatServerMarshaller)Activator.GetObject(requiredType,
"tcp://localhost:4567/CatServerMarshaller");

string catStatus;

try
{
    catStatus = remoteObject.GetCatStatus().ToString();
}
catch (SocketException ex)
{
    catStatus = "Offline";
}
finally
{
    ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(tcpChannel);
}

return Json(new { catStatus = catStatus});
```

Comment: Have you considered using SignalR? http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: Nice but you won't be able to hit the servers directly from the browser, it will ajax to the MVC backend and then the MVC backend will tcp to the server. I could use it for that part I guess, but still doesn't solve the problem above